# BackgroundWorker to check value in UI

Tags: c#, user-interface, backgroundworker

I found that my BackgroundWorker won't get values from UI.
I want BackgroundWorker to check if radiobutton is checked, but it's not doing it.
Here is code for my BackgroundWorker:

```
private void Worker2()
{
    worker2.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker2.DoWork += (obj, ea) => installDrivers();
    worker2.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(progressReport);
    worker2.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

And my method to run:

```
public void installDrivers()
{
     //insDriverTxt();
    // worker2.ReportProgress(30);

    //copy desktop power profiles:
    if ((bool)Desktop.IsChecked)
    {
        DirectoryCopy("X:\\PowerProfiles\\Desktop", "C:\\Tools", true);
        worker2.ReportProgress(30);
    }
    //graphic cards:
    //geforce:
    if ((bool)geforce.IsChecked)
    { 
        DirectoryCopy("X:\\Drivers\\nVidia\\Graphics", "C:\\Tools\\Drivers\\nVidia\\Graphics", true);
        for (int i = 31; i < 40; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            worker2.ReportProgress(i);
        }
        var geforce_install = Process.Start("C:\\Tools\\Drivers\\nVidia\\Graphics\\Setup.exe", "-n -s");
        geforce_install.WaitForExit();
        worker2.ReportProgress(40);
    }
}
```

Comment: pass the checkbox value in to the worker thread via a parameter. The reason it isn't working is that it's not possible to access UI components directly from a worker thread. They can only be accessed from the UI (main) thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a UI control from a background thread, which is what the Backgroundworker uses.

If you want to pass parameters to the worker, use the [RunWorkerAsync(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f00zz5b2(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that accepts an argument object. You can access the `argument` object you passed through the [DoWorkEventArgs.Argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.argument(v=vs.110).aspx) property. The property's documentation displays how to use it, eg:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Do not access the form's BackgroundWorker reference directly. 
    // Instead, use the reference provided by the sender parameter.
    BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    // Extract the argument. 
    int arg = (int)e.Argument;**
    ...
}
```

You can pass any type of object, just don't try to pass a UI control there, or you'll have the same problem!

A quick and dirty solution for passing multiple arguments is to use a `dynamic` object or a `Tuple`, eg:

```
var argument=Tuple.Create(Desktop.IsChecked,geforce.IsChecked);
worker2.RunWorkerAsync(argument);

...

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Do not access the form's BackgroundWorker reference directly. 
    // Instead, use the reference provided by the sender parameter.
    BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    // Extract the argument. 
    var myArguments=(Tuple<bool,bool>)e.Argument;
    var desktopIsChecked = (bool)myArguments.Item1;
    var geforceIsChecked = (bool)myArguments.Item2;
    ...
}
```

A better solution is to create a class for passing specific arguments

Comment: when I use that
    var argument=Tuple.Create(Desktop.IsChecked,geforce.IsChecked);
    worker2.RunWorkerAsync(argument);
it doesn't do anything. Any suggestions? I'm new to background worker

Comment: What does `doesn't do anything` mean? Are you getting an exception? Did you try to debug the application? If you are new to async programming, it's better to abandon BackgroundWorker completely and use the new `TPL`/`async` features in .NET 4+

Comment: i mean it's still not copying/installing drivers.

Comment: That *is* a different question, that can't be answered since you don't provide the code for `DirectoryCopy`. Did you debug the event handler? Are you reaching any breakpoints inside it? Also note that the event handler blocks while copying, then starts blocking again while reporting progress. The code waits for copying to finish before waiting for about 5 secs.

Comment: Copy/install works perfectly fine when launched in main thread, but then it locked ui, hence trying to use background worker. There is many more bg workers and they work fine as they don't take values from ui, and progress reports are ok as well.